# eclipse compiles but not runs

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have been using eclipse cdt for project development for a while.
suddenly, a couple of days ago on wards, eclipse compiles but doesn't run(i can run the executable from commanline though).
I need your help to get it working again.

if you need any more information, please ask in the comments so that I can help you to help me out.
Thanks

Comment: What version of Eclipse CDT? The content of eclipse.ini might also be needed. Are there any Exceptions in the Log-Files of Eclipse (under workspace/.metadata)?

Comment: Isn't that the moment to use `emacs` instead?

Comment: Is the configuration present in the run configurations ? Sometimes it is removed on breaching limit?  Also if there are multiple projects open you must select the project and then click run other wise it wont find the executable to run.

Comment: @AdnanAkbar I try to run through selecting 'run configurations' manually. still same problem

Comment: can you please paste the output of eclipse console ?

Comment: @AdnanAkbar it is huge(code base is laaaarge) but it finally says build finished(as it always used to say)

Comment: nope check the run console , You can see different consoles in the dropdown at the right top of console window.

Comment: @Burkhard I am using eclipse version 3.8.0, I will just paste the eclipse ini in the question , and log file.. i just checked, there was a .log file in that folder with many exceptions. the file date was for today!. anyway, I deleted to file to see whether it is regenerated after I try to run my application or not, the file was not created again.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25337/discussion-between-adnan-akbar-and-rahman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The previous runing applicatios were the reason you were not able to run the application. First you should check that there is no previously running application present in the debug perspective.